# Delay within an if in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay, coroutine

How can I create a delay after the fade in, so that the text stays on screen for a few seconds? I used an `IEnumerator` and a coroutine, but it does nothing. I also tried placing it right after the first `else`.

What happens at the moment is the text fades out before having the chance to fade in. The text appears momentarily in semi-clear and disappears. It's for a Unity project.

Also, `Thread.Sleep` won't do.

Here's the piece of code in question:

```
IEnumerator Pause ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D interCollider)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        displayInfo = true;
    }
    else
    {
        displayInfo = false;
    }
}

void FadeText()
{
    if (displayInfo == true)
    {
        text1.text = string1;
        text1.color = Color.Lerp(text1.color, Color.white, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(Pause());
        text1.color = Color.Lerp(text1.color, Color.clear, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is very important that you add the `unity3d` tag to unity questions. If you don't you will get answers for writing desktop applications that does not apply to Unity3d

Comment: Also, you need to show how `FadeText` is called. it will provide relevent context to how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should read:

```
void Update()
{
    if (fadingOut)
    {
        // fade out with lerp here
    }
}

IEnumerator Pause()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
    fadingOut = true;
}

void FadeText()
{
    if (displayInfo == true)
    {
        text1.text = string1;
        text1.color = Color.Lerp(text1.color, Color.white, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(Pause());
    }
}
```

You have the right idea of using a coroutine, but didn't quite get the execution right. When you invoke a method on coroutine, it will be executed in parallel with the main thread.  In your code, the `Pause()` method is running alongside the `Color.Lerp`.  If you want the fading to wait until *after* the pause is complete, they must be on the same coroutine.

**Edit:**
As pointed out, this won't work if you're calling FadeText() on each frame.  But this shows you how you can easily set a flag and wait until the pause time is complete before fading.

Comment: If FadeText gets called once per frame I don't know if this is going to provide the correct behavior. I think the OP wants a 5 second pause then it starts to fade out, this is going to make it fade out in 5 second steps.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ah good call... I updated my answer.  Still technically won't work if FadeText is being called multiple times, but if the fade in is adapted the same way it should be good to go

Comment: I guess that's why it's called a "COroutine", should have thought of it, thanks! I put FadeText() elsewhere and now workes as intended! :D

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the text fade to the coroutine.

```
IEnumerator Pause()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5);
    text1.color = Color.Lerp(text1.color, Color.clear, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

And just start the coroutine in your else statement. This way it will execute the wait for seconds, and then the fade whenever you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way is to use LeanTween asset. It's free and have a lot of other usefull features that I use in EVERY project.

It's really awesome lib.

```
LeanTween.DelayedCall(1f,()=>{ /*any code that will be called after 1 second will pass*/ });
```

or

```
LeanTween.DelayedCall(1f, SomeMethodWithoutParams());
```